# How to edit Unity multitouch gestures?

Tags: unity, touchpad, multi-touch, gestures

I can't find a way to modify the touchpad gestures Unity uses by default on Ubuntu 12.04/12.10.

Tried with `Ginn`, but it shows `error subscribing to gestures` and it seems because of Unity.

Is there a way of customize the trackpad gestures of Unity?

Answer (score 4):

The [Easystroke](https://sourceforge.net/projects/easystroke/files/) gesture-recognition app should be able to define some new multitouch gestures as well as edit existing ones. Apple's multi-touch trackpad and corresponding gesture recognition, is by far the best implementation of gesture tracking we've seen yet. Easystroke however, is a fair contender with the mac gesture recognition. Easystroke allows users to create gestures with their mouse that will perform specified actions, such as open a web browser or view mail.

Find more tips/tricks and application details at the [developer page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki/Documentation).

**Touchegg & uTouch**

Touchegg combined with the uTouch metapackage allow users to create and edit multi-touch gestures on a trackpad. These applications when downloaded from the Ubuntu Software center create an editable config file.

[image: Easystroke Image: Sourceforge.net]

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever use Easystroke gesture-recognition application ?
read this
[multitouch gestures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217889/multitouch-gestures)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Touchegg in ubuntu 14.04 to configure 3 finger swipe to switch workspaces like apple.  Searching around a little bit it seems it will work on 12.10.  However, I can't comment on the stability of it.  I've since migrated away from it and just use keyboard shortcuts.

[Download Page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/touchegg/wikis/CompileSourceCode.wiki)

[Install Help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248167/how-to-install-touchegg-on-ubuntu-12-10)

[What to do after successful install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252260/what-should-i-do-to-run-after-i-have-successfully-installed-touchegg-on-ubuntu-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `synclient` to edit configurations in touchpad.

```
$ synclient
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 49
    RightEdge               = 1187
    TopEdge                 = 48
    BottomEdge              = 850
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 67
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 30
    HorizScrollDelta        = 30
    VertEdgeScroll          = 1
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.130976
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    ...
```

To edit attribute use

```
synclient <attribute-name>=<value>
```