# Three fingers swipe and page back and forth in browser on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: multi-touch, trackpad, gestures

Is there anything that enables you to back and forth web pages in a browser with three fingers swipe on Ubuntu 13.04, as seamlessly as on OS X, if not better?

Google searching told me that `touchegg` would be a good fit for my purpose, but I later found that it supports only prior versions, not 13.04 currently. So are there any alternatives? Or if there doesn't exist, then how you guys (at least those using 13.04) do page back and forth in your browser? I believe that it's too painful either to put your cursor on arrows located at top left and click on those or put `Alt` + `<>` on your keyboard in order to do page back and forth.

I use Ubuntu on MacBook Pro trackpad and keyboard, for your information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much time now to write an elaborated answer, but you should have a look at [Easystroke](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easystroke/).
I use it and it's really great.

I use motions such as

- "twofinger-doubletab + stroke" to switch to another workspace (a bit "OSX-like")
- the corners of my touchpad are assigned to functions as "next/previous track", "workspace switcher" and "shot launcher"
- thee finger tab is set to "spread windows" (like super+w)
- ... (you can also combine geastures with a modifier key for even more possibilities)

Comment: Any documentations on it out there? Just installed it but I have no idea on how to do my custom touchpad setting nor wasn't able to find helpful tutorials on the Web...

Comment: I don't have time to find the documentation I used, but I think this question could be useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217889/multitouch-gestures

Also: the easystroke documentation: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki/Documentation

Comment: I can't understand how to set stroke. Do you use in in trackpad? It looks like both the documentation and every pages I saw on the Web assume mouse, not trackpad.

Comment: OK I can set some strokes. However, this doesn't support tap. Only click is supported, such as `click and then move your finger to the left`, which is pathetically inconvenient. Thanks for your answer, but I'm never comfortable with it.

Comment: For 14.04 see http://askubuntu.com/questions/92169/touchpad-gestures-to-change-workspace