# Multitouch Gestures in 12.10: disabling four-finger-swipe + re-configuring generally

Tags: 12.10, configuration, default, multi-touch

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch describes a set of default "Supported Gestures" that come with Ubuntu 12.10 -- and they work as described on my MacBook Pro 13" Retina.

But I can't figure out how to configure them.  I'm especially tripped up by the "4 finger swipe left/right to reveal launcher (if the dock autohide is enabled)", which apparently has the ability to turn off launcher auto-hide and occlude windows.

I'm also interested in configuring new gestures and/or remapping old ones.

I'd appreciate any advice about:

1. Disabling default multitouch gestures
2. Changing or creating new multitouch gestures

Thanks!

Please note that the following issues do not answer my question:

- [How can I disable the multitouch gestures in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133207/how-can-i-disable-the-multitouch-gestures-in-ubuntu) (I actually like the "drag handles" setting)
- [How to edit Unity multitouch gestures?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198059/how-to-edit-unity-multitouch-gestures) (Does not address diabling)

Answer (score 0):

Karhan, how did you manage to activate the Touchpad / Trackpad in Ubuntu 12.10? I'm very, very interested in this, because I could not figure it out at all.
I own a 13" Retina too, installed 12.10 with the two possibities, EFI-Boot and the dd+ alt method to boot from a memory stick a ubuntu amd64+mac.iso.
In any case, the Touchpad/Trackpad only works as a mouse with only 1 key :-(
I'll spend you a beer, if you can help me out - or two :-)

Regards
Dirk