# How to Install touchegg on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: compiling

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and I am trying to install touchegg so I can have multi-touch on my mousepad. I was following the guide [here](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/CompileSourceCode) but I am not able to compile the source for some reason. Can someone please help me?

When I reach the part that says to run `make` on the terminal I get:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: use pastebin.com and place all the log of your try.

Comment: *Where* did you run `make`? It sounds like you just ran make out of nowhere, instead of getting into the directory with the source files you just extracted from the archive you downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

first you must `qmake`, it will create a makefile document, then `make` then `sudo make install`

to install qmake: `sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake`