# What should I do to run after I have successfully installed touchegg on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, touchegg

I just have successfully installed [touchegg](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/Downloads?tm=2) and [touchegg gui](https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce) on my Ubuntu 12.10. But, right now I still can't use the multi touch gestures through touchegg. Nothing happen when I use my three fingers or more on the touch pad. But, the 2 fingers scroll from Ubuntu is still working well.

I am able to use the touchegg GUI configuration and set any kind of move that I want for my touch pad. But, it's not working.

So, what should I do to make the touchegg working?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do it disable the Unity default gestures:

**1. You have to download the Unity sourcecode:**

`sudo apt-get build-dep unity`

`cd /tmp`

`mkdir unity`

`cd unity`

`apt-get source unity`

**2. We the have to edit a file:**

`sudo gedit /tmp/unity/unity-*/plugins/unityshell/src/unityshell.cpp`

Then find: `void UnityScreen::InitGesturesSupport()` and comment out (add # to the start of the line) all the lines the start with `gestures_` that are in between the `{ and }`

**3. Now we have to rebuild the .deb file and install it**

`cd /tmp/unity/unity-*`

`dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc`

`cd ..`

`sudo dpkg -i *deb`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

**NOTE: You may want to stop Unity upgrading as it will re-activate the gestures if it does. this can be done by running the following command:**

`echo "unity hold"|sudo dpkg --set-selections`

**4.Reboot**
If it still isn't working after the reboot you may need to run some extra commands:

`synclient TapButton2=0`

`synclient TapButton3=0`

`synclient ClickFinger2=0`

`synclient ClickFinger3=0`

`synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0`

`synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0`

Hopefully this get you up and running