# how to install touchegg on ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: touchegg

I from iran and install ubuntu 14.10, but I have a big problem to install `touchegg` in this version and i want you help me.
...........
below instruction is not working:

```
sudo apt-get install
```

because when I type this in terminal show a message by this title:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 354 not upgraded.
```

and I don't know why this command not work...

please help me!

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install touchegg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the package lists before trying to install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

This can also be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center

[image: Install via the software center]

**Alternatively:** You can also download it on the [touchegg-website](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/Downloads?tm=2). There is a link to instructions, too.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run the following commands (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

Note: use `upgrade` command since you have many not upgraded files.After upgrade command still you have not upgraded files,use this command,

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You can also install from Software Centre:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: sorry for some comments.
i installed this but, how to use this?

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252260/what-should-i-do-to-run-after-i-have-successfully-installed-touchegg-on-ubuntu-1) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/544821/how-can-i-configure-touchegg-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I see these links.
and thank you.
but i run touchegg in terminal and see these messages:

[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Flick 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Drag 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Pinch 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Rotate 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Tap 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Touch

now! what do work?