# Do Dell Laptop Touch Screen Monitors Work with Ubuntu 12.04/12.10?

Tags: laptop, dell, touchscreen

I'm about to buy a Dell Precision m6700 that I plan on dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 (or 12.10, feel free to comment) and I'm wondering if I should get the touch screen monitor designed for Windows 8. I'll be working on a plane a lot so the touch screen might be a nice alternative to the track pad when I don't have room for a mouse. I found some people having trouble with it but I'm not sure if it works for most people. Also if you have it working it would be great to know if you find it useful.
Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no, in my experience (I have a 2013 XPS 15 w/ touch screen).  There's multiple minor problems that make it unreliable.  First, if you have multiple monitors plugged in, the touches on the screen will go to your "main" monitor, even if that isn't your laptop screen (obviously not a problem when you don't have external monitors plugged in).  Even when the touches are on the right screen, they rarely do what you want them to do.  For example, dragging your finger on a webpage selects text on the page, it doesn't scroll the page.

This could all be improved in newer versions of the kernel and/or ubuntu updates... but I wouldn't rely on it working.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be perfect out of the box, but with some effort you can make it work the way you want.

To address the points in Nate Finchs answer, for external non-touch monitors you can use the steps provided [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Calibrating_Touchscreen) to create two calibrations, one for single and one for dual monitor use.

Initially you touching the screen will always be interpreted as a click which explains the text being selected. But you can change the behavior greatly by using for example [Easystroke](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki).
you can find more information on how to configure multitouch gestures [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198059/how-to-edit-unity-multitouch-gestures).

Good luck!

Comment: Also be sure to use the official touchscreen drivers provided by Dell. You can find them at: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2013/11/14/ubuntu-on-the-precision-m3800.aspx